# Modal popup on dropdown list selection

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to popup a modal(AJAX) on drop downlist selection.
I have a user control which has  a ddl and another usercontrol which has that modal popup.On selection of specific item i need to popup modal.
Modal popup is in another usercontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did an example of how to do it entirely client side using a ClientEventPool - http://www.aaron-powell.com/blog/january-2009/fun-with-a-client-event-pool-and-modal-popups.aspx

For AJAX work avoid postbacks at all costs!

Comment: This is what I was referring to, this is a better example.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading you correctly, you will need to use either chained events or event bubbling to force the drop down selection to fire an event.  Then your second user control must listen for that event, and fire the event that "shows" the modal popup.

Without testing code, your structure on the primary control might look like this:

```
public delegate void DDLHandler(int selectedValue);

public event DDLHandler DDLChanged;

public void DDLChanged(int selection)
{
    if (DDLChanged != null)
    {
        DDLChanged(selection);
    }
}
```

Then you drop down control has it's event wired to call the handler

```
protected void ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //fire event handler for fetching value for this selection
    DDLChanged(Int32.Parse(ddlMeasurementOptions.SelectedValue));
}
```